# Changing object causes changes in all objects

Tags: javascript

have such type of object.
Creating elemens in FabricJS canvas and setting attributes:

```
canvas.forEachObject(function (e) {
        e.hasControls = e.hasBorders = false; //remove borders/controls
        e.isStatic = true;
        e.corners = [false, false, false, false, false];
    });


fitElement.destination.corners[1] = true;
fitElement.origin.corners[3] = true;

console.log(fitElement.destination.corners);
console.log(fitElement.origin.corners);
```

And the result is

```
[false, true, false, true, false]
[false, true, false, true, false]
```

Why changing one array in object causes the chages of another?
What I am doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Please provide a complete example. The code you posted will never produce this output (it can't even run). Assuming `fitElement` is a simply object, this code does not produce the output you claim: http://jsfiddle.net/vLL8p47a/

Comment: Im willing to bet the actual code is not like that - Are you sure both arrays are not references to the same array? That would certainly explain the behaviour you're seeing: http://jsfiddle.net/vLL8p47a/1/

Comment: Sorry, code is so big. But you were right - both arrays are not references to the same array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's only one explanation: `fitElement.destination.corners` and `fitElement.origin.corners` are the very same array.

Somewhere up in the your code you assign one array or object to the other, so you are referencing the same data in memory, for example:

```
var vector5 = new Vector5(); // of my invention, just to explain the concept

fitElement.origin.corners = vector5;
fitElement.destination.corners = vector5;
```

Or:

```
fitElement.origin.corners = vector5;
fitElement.destination.corners = fitElement.origin.corners;
```

Or a step up in the nesting:

```
fitElement.origin.corners = vector5;
fitElement.destination = fitElement.origin;
```

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript variables for the vast majority of objects are references, which leads to issues like this. Somewhere in your code, you almost certainly do the equivalent of `destination.corners = foo; ... origin.corners = foo;` and end up using the same array for both.

You can test this easily enough by asking if `fitElement.destination.corners === fitElement.origin.corners` after assigning. The `===` ([strict equality](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Identity)) operator check if both variables reference the same object. In this case, I'll bet they do and that's the source of your problem.

The most common way of accidentally doing that -- in my experience -- is passing a parent object or taking a property from one or more objects that happen to point to the same array. For example, doing:

```
var foo = {bar: [1, 2, 3]};
var baz = _.extend({}, foo); // create a "copy"

foo.bar[1] = 9;
console.log(baz.bar);
```

While the parent object (`foo` -> `baz`) is cloned and `foo !== baz`, the child (`bar`) is *not* and any changes to `foo.bar` will also affect `baz.bar`.

Libraries that offer a copy/clone/extend function may also provide a deep clone that will walk down the object and clone any children as well (for example, lodash provides [clone](https://lodash.com/docs#clone) and [cloneDeep](https://lodash.com/docs#cloneDeep).

In your case, since you're using the arrays individually, I would suggest making a copy of each just before assigning them to the corners. You can copy an array with [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice):

```
var defaultCorners = [false,false,false,false,false];
var destCorners = defaultCorners.slice();
var originCorners = defaultCorners.slice();

fitElement.destination.corners = destCorners;
fitElement.origin.corners = originCorners; 

destCorners[1] = true;
originCorners[3] = true;

console.log(fitElement.destination.corners);
console.log(fitElement.origin.corners);
```

This will avoid the problem, but remember: `slice` makes another shallow copy, so any objects within the array will have this same issue.

Comment: Please don't call this "pass-by-reference". Objects are represented **as** references, but that has nothing to do with "pass-by-reference": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_reference. Relevant: *"Call-by-reference can be simulated in languages that use call-by-value and don't exactly support call-by-reference, by making use of references (objects that refer to other objects), such as pointers (objects representing the memory addresses of other objects)."*

Comment: You are wright. I was copying objects from this one(in description) with those params. Each time the bject was copied params vere linked to each other.